# Check address from Melissa server

Tags: java, performance

How can I improve this code?

```
public String checkAddressFromMelissaServer(boolean isEditMode, boolean addressChecked, Address address) {
        boolean isAddress = false;
        boolean isError = true;
        String SystemResult = "";
        boolean systemErrorFlag = false;
        StringBuffer requestAddress = new StringBuffer();
        Address returnAddress = null;
        StringBuffer addressNew = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer addressReturn = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            if (address != null && address.getHouse() != null) {
                requestAddress.append(address.getHouse());
            }
            if (address != null && address.getStreetPrefix() != null) {
                requestAddress.append(" ").append(address.getStreetPrefix());
            }
            if (address != null && address.getStreet() != null) {
                requestAddress.append(" ").append(address.getStreet());
            }
            if (address != null && address.getStreetType() != null) {
                requestAddress.append(" ").append(address.getStreetType());
            }
            if (address != null && address.getStreetDirection() != null) {
                requestAddress.append(" ").append(address.getStreetDirection());
            }
            if (address != null && address.getCity() != null) {
                requestAddress.append(" ").append(address.getCity());
            }
            if (address != null && address.getCity() != null) {
                requestAddress.append(" ").append(address.getCity());
            }
            if (address != null && address.getProvince() != null) {
                requestAddress.append(" ").append(address.getProvince());
            }
            if (address != null && address.getPostal() != null) {
                requestAddress.append(" ").append(address.getPostal());
            }

            AddressVerificationAdaptor addressVerificationAdaptor = getAddressAdaptor();
            if (addressVerificationAdaptor != null) {

                returnAddress = addressVerificationAdaptor.verifyAddress(address);

                if (returnAddress != null) {

                    addressReturn.append(returnAddress.getHouse()).append(":").append(returnAddress.getStreetPrefix()).append(":")
                            .append(returnAddress.getStreet()).append(":").append(returnAddress.getStreetType()).append(":")
                            .append(returnAddress.getStreetDirection()).append(":").append(returnAddress.getCity()).append(":")
                            .append(returnAddress.getProvince()).append(":").append(returnAddress.getPostal());

                    if (returnAddress.getHouse() != null && returnAddress.getHouse().length() > 0)
                        addressNew.append((returnAddress.getHouse() == null) ? "" : returnAddress.getHouse());

                    if (returnAddress.getStreetPrefix() != null && returnAddress.getStreetPrefix().length() > 0) {
                        addressNew.append(" ").append((returnAddress.getStreetPrefix() == null) ? "" : returnAddress.getStreetPrefix());
                    }
                    if (returnAddress.getStreet() != null && returnAddress.getStreet().length() > 0) {
                        addressNew.append(" ").append(returnAddress.getStreet() == null ? "" : returnAddress.getStreet());

                    }
                    if (returnAddress.getStreetType() != null && returnAddress.getStreetType().length() > 0) {
                        addressNew.append(" ").append(returnAddress.getStreetType() == null ? "" : returnAddress.getStreetType());

                    }
                    if (returnAddress.getStreetDirection() != null && returnAddress.getStreetDirection().length() > 0) {
                        addressNew.append(" ").append(returnAddress.getStreetDirection() == null ? "" : returnAddress.getStreetDirection());

                    }
                    if (returnAddress.getCity() != null && returnAddress.getCity().length() > 0) {
                        addressNew.append(" ").append(returnAddress.getCity() == null ? "" : returnAddress.getCity());

                    }
                    if (returnAddress.getProvince() != null && returnAddress.getProvince().length() > 0) {
                        addressNew.append(" ").append(returnAddress.getProvince() == null ? "" : returnAddress.getProvince());

                    }
                    if (returnAddress.getPostal() != null && returnAddress.getPostal().length() > 0) {
                        addressNew.append(" ").append(returnAddress.getPostal() == null ? "" : returnAddress.getPostal());

                    }

                    SystemResult = returnAddress.getSystemErrorString();

                    if (addressChecked) { // to check for address check is enabled
                        isAddress = true;
                    } else {
                        addressNew = new StringBuffer(returnAddress.getErrorString());
                    }
                } else {
                    isError = false;
                    String returnValue = "Error";
                    return returnValue;
                }
            }

            String toshowErrorCode = "";
            String additionalErrorCodes = "";
            int countErrorCode = 0;
            if (returnAddress.getErrorString().length() > 0) {
                String splitErrorString[] = returnAddress.getErrorString().split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i < splitErrorString.length; i++) {
                    if (splitErrorString[i].contains("AE")) {
                        if (countErrorCode == 0) {
                            toshowErrorCode = splitErrorString[i];
                            countErrorCode++;
                        } else
                            additionalErrorCodes = additionalErrorCodes + splitErrorString[i] + ",";
                    }
                }
            }

            if (additionalErrorCodes.endsWith(","))
                additionalErrorCodes = additionalErrorCodes.substring(0, additionalErrorCodes.length() - 1);

            if (addressNew.toString().trim().equals("") && SystemResult.trim().length() > 1) {
                systemErrorFlag = true;
            }

            String returnValue = "Success" + ";" + isAddress + ";" + addressNew + ";" + requestAddress + ";" + SystemResult + ";" + systemErrorFlag
                    + ";" + toshowErrorCode + ";" + additionalErrorCodes + ";" + isEditMode + ";" + isError + ";" + addressReturn;
            return returnValue;

        } catch (AddressVerificationException addressException) {
            LOGGER.error("", addressException);
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: `if (address != null && address.getCity() != null) {` and the code block is duplicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code could be more efficient, in that it could be written more compactly.  However, I don't see anything that would cause a noticeable performance impact.  If you're connecting to a remote server to verify an address, I would expect that the time to send, process, and receive that request would dwarf whatever time it takes to concatenate a few strings.

I have much deeper concerns about this code than performance.

### Error handling

This line, in particular, has me very worried:

> ```
> } else {
>     addressNew = new StringBuffer(returnAddress.getErrorString());                                                      
> }
> ```

**Always distinguish error messages from legitimate data.**  Do not output them through the same channel.  Here's a real-life example of what happens when error messages are accidentally treated as data:

[image: Nid wyf yn y swyddfa ar hyn o bryd. Anfonwch unrhyw waith i'w gyfieithu.]

That's [Welsh for "I am not in the office at the moment. Send any work to be translated."](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/7702913.stm)

Don't let that happen to users of this function.  In Java, the right thing to do when you encounter an error is to throw an exception.  That forces a caller somewhere in the call stack to deal with the error as an error, and helps prevent mix-ups like this.

### Return values

It's not clear what this function is supposed to return.  Here's the return for the "desired" code path:

> ```
> String returnValue = "Success" + ";" + isAddress + ";" + addressNew + ";" + requestAddress + ";" + SystemResult + ";" + systemErrorFlag
>         + ";" + toshowErrorCode + ";" + additionalErrorCodes + ";" + isEditMode + ";" + isError + ";" + addressReturn;
> return returnValue;
> ```

However, there is one possible failure scenario:

> ```
> String returnValue = "Error";
> return returnValue;
> ```

… and a third possible outcome:

> ```
> } catch (AddressVerificationException addressException) {
>     LOGGER.error("", addressException);
> }
> return null;
> ```

**The existence of these three possibilities makes your function difficult to use correctly.**  The caller will need to check whether the  `null`, and if it's not null, whether the text starts with `"Success;"`, and if so, interpret the result by splitting the text at semicolons.  There's a good chance that the caller will be sloppily optimistic and neglect to handle the two error conditions.

**Never return `null` to indicate failure.**  It may be OK to use `null` to  signify "no such value exists" — for example, that there is no street prefix.  Failures need to be conveyed through separate channels, as discussed above.  For that matter, why should `getAddressAdaptor()` ever return `null`?  By returning `null` instead of throwing an exception, `getAddressAdaptor()` is foisting on this function the same burden that this function is foisting on its caller.

A semicolon-delimited result is also unwieldy.  It would be better to **return an `AddressVerificationResult` object.**  If the result really does need to be in string form because it will need to be transmitted over a stream, then use a standard serialization format like [json](/questions/tagged/json), [xml](/questions/tagged/xml), or [yaml](/questions/tagged/yaml).

### Offload the string concatenation code

All of that code to concatenate the various `Address` fields into a string should be moved into a `toString()` method of the `Address` class.

In the part of the code where you do this…

> ```
> if (returnAddress.getHouse() != null && returnAddress.getHouse().length() > 0)
>     addressNew.append((returnAddress.getHouse() == null) ? "" : returnAddress.getHouse());
> ```

… the ternary expressions are pointless, because you've already ascertained that `getHouse()` is non-null.  Also, be sure to use braces consistently for all if-statements.

### Keep it simple

What are the parameters `isEditMode` and `addressChecked` for?  What influence could they possibly have over whether a given address is valid or not?  It seems that they just end up being plopped into fields within the semicolon-delimited result string.

Simplify this function by having it **do one thing only** — and get rid of irrelevant complications.

Answer (score 3):

### Key point #1: Are you doing your error handling correctly? ([@200_success's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/92728/27975))

### Key point #2: **return early**!

1. **`StringBuilder` vs `StringBuffer`**

   [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is preferred over `StringBuffer` unless you require the synchronization benefits offered by `StringBuffer`:

   > As of release JDK 5, this class ([*`StringBuffer`*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)) has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, `StringBuilder`. The `StringBuilder` class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization.
2. **Printing addresses**

   Is it possible for your `Address` class to provide another method, e.g. `asFullAddress()` (or maybe just override its `toString()`), which can take care of the concatenating of house/street prefix/street etc. for you?

   If not, you should perform the checks in its own method, and here's a suggestion using Java 8's [`Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) feature:

   ```
   private static String getFullAddress(Address address) {
       if (address == null) {
           return "";
       }
       return Stream.of(address.getHouse(), address.getStreetPrefix(), ...)
                   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                   .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
   }
   ```

   What that does is to create a `Stream` of all your address components, [`filter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) for those which are not null, and then concatenate them with a `" "` between using [`Collectors.joining(CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-).

   The code then gets simplified as:

   ```
   String requestAddress = getFullAddress(address);
   ```
3. **Address verification and `try-catch` scope**

   Your address verification part (`AddressVerificationAdaptor addressVerificationAdaptor = getAddressAdaptor();` onwards) should also belong to its own method that can be called here.

   You should also reduce the scope of your `try-catch` to only the block where the `Exception` might be thrown. The idea of catching `Exception`s is to let your code logic know how to recover from said `Exception`s, so a general 'catch-all' block that makes recovery hard is kind of self-defeating. If one may assume from the name of your `Exception`, the `try-catch` should then be moved to this address verification method:

   ```
   // assuming getAddressAdaptor() can't be made static
   private Address verifyAddress(Address address) {
       AddressVerificationAdaptor adaptor = getAddressAdaptor();
       try {
           return adaptor == null ? null : adaptor.verifyAddress(address);
       } catch (AddressVerificationException e) {
           LOGGER.error("", addressException);
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```
4. **Further refinements**

   Once again, when you have extracted the steps required to generate a full address from an `Address` object, you should use that to simplify the following chunk too:

   ```
   addressReturn.append(returnAddress.getHouse()).append(":")...
   ```

   Since it looks like your delimiter is a `":"` here, you can definitely modify the method to accept that as an argument too, e.g.

   ```
   private static String getFullAddress(Address address, String delimiter) {
       // exactly the same as above, except for the last line
       return Stream.of(...)
                   // ...
                   .collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter));
   }
   ```

   **Good news**, your `addressNew` appears to be the same as `addressReturn` but using the `" "` as a delimiter, so you get to use the method ***again***!

   ```
   public String checkAddressFromMelissaServer(...) {
       // ...
       String requestAddress = getFullAddress(address, " ");
       Address returnAddress = verifyAddress(address);
       if (returnAddress == null) {
           // isError = false; <- this is redundant since you are returning from here
           return "Error";
       }
       String addressReturn = getFullAddress(returnAddress, ":");
       String addressNew = addressChecked ? getFullAddress(returnAddress, " ") 
                                               : returnAddress.getErrorString();
       // note: camelCase below
       String systemResult = returnAddress.getSystemErrorString();
       // ...
   }
   ```
5. **Checking error codes**

   BTW, you can also use the enhanced `for`-loop for looping, since you are only using `i` as an index. Initially, I was about to suggest not having to distinguish between your first error code `toShowErrorCode` and the additional ones `additionalErrorCodes`, but since they appear to be formatted slightly differently at the end, I guess you still can...

   ```
   private static List<String> getErrorCodes(Address address) {
       if (address.getErrorString().isEmpty()) {
           return Collections.emptyList();
       }
       return errorCodes = Stream.of(returnAddress.getErrorString().split(","))
                   .filter(v -> v.contains("AE"))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
   }

   public String checkAddressFromMelissaServer(...) {
       // ...
       String systemResult = returnAddress.getSystemErrorString();
       List<String> errorCodes = getErrorCodes(returnAddress);
       String firstErrorCode = errorCodes().isEmpty() ? "" : errorCodes.get(0);
       String additionalErrorCodes = errorCodes.stream().skip(1)
                                       .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
   }
   ```

### Putting it all together

```
    private static String getFullAddress(Address address, String delimiter) {
        if (address == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return Stream.of(address.getHouse(), address.getStreetPrefix() /* , ... */)
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter));
    }

    private Address verifyAddress(Address address) {
        AddressVerificationAdaptor adaptor = getAddressAdaptor();
        try {
            return adaptor == null ? null : adaptor.verifyAddress(address);
        } catch (AddressVerificationException e) {
            LOGGER.error("", addressException);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static List<String> getErrorCodes(Address address) {
        return errorCodes = Stream.of(address.getErrorString().split(","))
                    .filter(v -> v.contains("AE"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public String checkAddressFromMelissaServer(...) {
        String requestAddress = getFullAddress(address, " ");
        Address returnAddress = verifyAddress(address);
        if (returnAddress == null) {
            return "Error";
        }
        String addressReturn = getFullAddress(returnAddress, ":");
        String addressNew = addressChecked ? getFullAddress(returnAddress, " ") 
                                                : returnAddress.getErrorString();
        String systemResult = returnAddress.getSystemErrorString();
        List<String> errorCodes = getErrorCodes(returnAddress);
        String firstErrorCode = errorCodes().isEmpty() ? "" : errorCodes.get(0);
        String additionalErrorCodes = errorCodes.stream().skip(1)
                                        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        Boolean systemErrorFlag = Boolean.valueOf(addressNew.trim.isEmpty() 
                                        && systemResult.trim().length() > 1);
        return Stream.of("Success", Boolean.valueOf(addressChecked), addressNew, 
                        requestAddress, systemResult, systemErrorFlag, 
                        firstErrorCode, additionalErrorCodes, 
                        Boolean.valueOf(isEditMode), Boolean.FALSE, addressReturn)
                    .map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(";"));
    }
```